# c# loop through dictionary passed through session

Tags: c#, asp.net

I created and added items to this dictionary and set it to session. Now I'm trying to retrieve the session in another page and loop through the dictionary, how do I do so? I tried using foreach loop but the membersDictionary variable seems to be not a dictionary, how do I loop through the dictionary passed to session? Please help, thanks.

Home.aspx.cs

```
Dictionary<string, string> membersDictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();
membersDictionary.Add(TB_member1Username.Text, TB_member1mobile.Text);
membersDictionary.Add(TB_member2Username.Text, TB_member2mobile.Text);
Session["FamPlanMembersDict"] = membersDictionary;
```

Home2.aspx.cs

```
var membersDictionary = Session["FamPlanMembersDict"];
foreach(var item in membersDictionary)
{
      .....
}
```

Comment: u just need to cast it as its type `(Dictionary<string, string>)Session["FamPlanMembersDict"];`

Answer (score 1):

Cast it as a dictionary of two strings as follows:

```
Dictionary<string, string> membersDictionary = Session["session_values"] as Dictionary<string, string>;
foreach(var item in membersDictionary)
{
      .....
}
```

Comment: The community encourages adding explanations alongisde code, rather than purely code-based answers (see [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300837/what-comment-should-i-add-to-code-only-answers)).

Comment: @costaparas OK.

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to cast it

```
var membersDictionary = (Dictionary<string, string>)Session["FamPlanMembersDict"];
foreach(var item in membersDictionary)
{
      .....
}
```

Though quite old [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/03sekbw5(v=vs.100)) also states the same. The `Session` output is `object` as we wanted to be able to save everything there.